# распарсить строку в JSON

Tags: javascript

К примеру есть строка вида

```
'test[test2][test3]'
```

Как с помощью javascript распарсить ее в JSON вида

```
{
    "test": {
        "test2": {
            "test3": null
        }
    }
}
```

?

При этом количество уровней может отличаться и заранее неизвестно.

Нашел [пример на jQuery](https://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/MyWZdN), хотелось бы на чистом js, к примеру 6 версии (или какая там сейчас актуальна)

Comment: JSON.parse(<String_JSON>) - преобразует строку в объект

Comment: Мне обычную строку в JSON. Вот нашел пример, но там на jQuery https://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/MyWZdN Думаю для того кто в теме тут одной строкой все можно сделать на ES6 к примеру, только вот я не в теме совсем :)

Comment: Пример по ссылке написан на чистом JS (часть про парсинг)

Comment: И ? Я сделал то что нужно уже, пока умники вроде вас строчили комменты про отсутствие jQuery, который там присутствует. Не знаете как помочь - проходите мимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения, можно воспользоваться следующим подходом: получить все имена свойств в виде массива, свернуть получившийся массив в объект.

Для получения имен свойств можно использовать регулярное выражение и [метод `match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
str.match(/\w+/g)
```

Данное выражение вернет массив названий в порядке следования:

```
["test", "test2", "test3"]
```

Далее этот массив можно свернуть с помощью [функции `reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)

Данная функции проходит массив начиная с последнего элемента.

Вызов может быть следующим:

```
.reduceRight((acc,cur)=>({[cur]:acc}),null)
```

В качестве начального значения указывается `null`, это будет значение самого вложенного элемента.

Сама функция возвращает объект с одним свойством, имя которого находится в параметре `cur`, в который передается текущий элемент массива, значением свойства устанавливается объект полученный на предыдущем шаге.

Пример:

```js
console.log('test[test2][test3]'
  .match(/\w+/g)
  .reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({
    [cur]: acc
  }), null));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Есть еще адекватные люди здесь :)